# How to Condense and Transpose Data in a Set

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a data set like the following in a csv file:

```
TIME      NAME    VALUE
1:00am    A       1
1:00am    B       2
1:00am    C       3
1:00am    D       4
2:00am    A       1
2:00am    B       2
2:00am    C       3
2:00am    D       4
```

How would I modify the data such that the format ends up as:

```
TIME      A    B    C    D
1:00am    1    2    3    4
2:00am    1    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a pivot table. | Insert tab > Tables > PivotTable |

- Row Labels = Time
- Column Labels = Name
- Values = Sum of Values